# SQL : Split numeric string from as specific position by using commas as indicator

Tags: sql

I have two columns in my data. Column1 contains the numeric strings where digits are separated by commas and Column2 contains a number. I want to truncate the column1 by using the column2 as the position identifier for comma starting from right end of the string.

| Column1 | Column2 | Expected_OP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0,12,38,69,96,127,159,187 | 2 | 0,12,38,69,96,127 |
| 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 | 3 | 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 |
| 0,0,0,0,0,0 | 4 | 0,0 |

Comment: Choose a database

Comment: Don't tag spam. MySQL <> SQL Server <> PostgreSQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using? What have **you** tried to solve your problem? Why didn't it work? [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Honestly, the real solution here seems to be "fix your design; don't store delimited data in your (relational) database."

Comment: The data comes from our vendor, hence we do not have control over it Sir

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: *"hence we do not have control over it Sir"* Please don't assume the genders of users here; I make no mention of how I identify in this question, nor in my profile. If you don't know the user's gender, use gender neutral language please. And even *if* the data is coming from a 3rd party in a denormalised form, that doesn't mean you then `INSERT` it into your database in the same denormalised form; you can still fix it even if the third party won't.

Comment: It is easier to handle such problems in the fromt-end (the application) using a high level programming language with string functions like split, join, etc.

Comment: I have tried using RTRIM and SUBSTRING function but did not obtain the desired result as  numeric digits vary in 1s,10s,100s. @Larnu fixing the database is not currently an option due to huge size and cost associated

Comment: @VinayDalal you still need to tell us *what* RDBMS you are using after you spammed the tags...

Comment: I am using REDSHIFT (postgreSQL) @la

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working one, with a bit of trial-and-error:

```
select column1, column2, substr(column1,1,instr(column1,',',1,length(column1) - length(replace(column1,',','')) - column2 + 1) - 1) from test
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=294b41380fa60695550704ae8aea1e39)*

(Used postgresql) (Note, there is no error-checking with regards to invalid input (example no commas or too high number in column2)